# Reduction of Butterworth low pass filter to ideal low pass filter and gaussian lowpass filter

Tags: imageprocessing, filtering

While studying frequency domain filtering in computer vision, i came across this topic where the Butterworth low pass filter reduces to ideal low pass filer for large value of n and also reduces to gaussian low pass filter for small value of n. Here n is the order of filter.

Transfer function for Butterworth LPF is:
**H(u, v) = 1 / (1 + (D(u, v) / D0)^(2n))**

Transfer function for Gaussian LPF is:
**H(u, v) = exp(-(D(u, v)^2) / (2 * D0^2))**

Is there any mathematical derivation to get transfer function of Gaussian LPF from Butterworth LPF?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you explain the terms used in your formula and link where the formulas came from?